# keystore and sha1 similarity identifying on different account

Tags: android, flutter, keystore

My question
I have a play console in which I launched few apps. now I want to launch apps in different different dev accounts. So for launching I need to generate different keystore from the same pc. now the is question is there any similarities in keys generated from one pc or any threads which I don't know.and how many type of this keys can come into play.
I am a beginner in this area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**: There are NO similarities between keys generated from anywhere. The probability of two SHA1 colliding is close to NONE. ([You can read more about it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)) For this question, "I don't know.and how many type of this keys can come into play", you can have as many keys as you want, as keys are collision resistant.

---

Since you have introduced yourself as a beginner, I want to help you with more details. Here is my advice for you from my past experiences.

In order to launch the same app from multiple accounts:

**Things that must be done**:

1. Change the bundle ID (aka. package name)
2. Generate a new signing key
3. Review "Gradle Scripts" (ex. VersionCode, keystore.properties, etc..)

**Things I recommend to do:**

1. Switch to a new Firebase Project (If you are using one)
2. Renew existing 3rd party libraries with Keys (ex. Facebook SDK)
3. Check with your Payment Gateway provider if changes should be made.

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I want to do freelance so, I am sacred that different people will launch their app build by my pc, please advice me

Comment: Hey @Noobdeveloper,  "Different people will launch their app build by my pc" <-- Yes, this is possible but only means that they CAN launch their app with THEIR OWN Developer Account. But why should you be scared of this anyway? But as to "can different people launch their app with MY developer credentials?", the answer clearly is NO. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: @Noobdeveloper Just keep your keystore and Google Developer Account private& secret, and everything will be safe and sound.